# Syntax for submitting a mutation to a graphql-relay mutationWithClientMutationId

Tags: relayjs, graphql, graphql-js

I defined a GraphQL Mutation using graphql-relay but am having issues figuring out how to submit a mutation to it.

Here is the relevant schema:

```
const userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'user',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: 'The UUID for the user.',
      resolve(user) {
        return user.uuid;
      },
    },
  })
});

const registerUser = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'registerUser',
  inputFields: {
  },
  outputFields: {
    user: {
      type: userType,
      resolve: (payload) => {
        models.user.findById(payload.userId);
      }
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: (args) => {
    var newUser = models.user.build().save();
    return {
      userId: newUser.id,
    };
  }
});


const rootMutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootMutationType',
  fields: {
    registerUser: registerUser,
  },
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: rootQuery,
  mutation: rootMutation,
});
```

What should an HTTP call look like to register a new user and get back the  userId?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a mutation format that worked:

```
mutation RootMutationType {
  registerUser(input:{clientMutationId:"123"}){
    clientMutationId, user { id }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that I see that you're saying that your mutation requires no parameters - how does it know what the new user's details are? You'll probably need some parameters on that mutation, eventually. They would be available to your `mutateAndGetPayload` on that first function parameter. (I'm not saying every mutation needs parameters, but this one probably does)

If you're using Relay, there is some pretty good information on the [official document](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#content) as to how to use your mutations from Relay. Particularly down at the bottom where it shows the various mutator configs. If you're using connections, you may want to use `RANGE_ADD` to add this new account to the Relay store manually, otherwise if you'd like to perform a more broad refetch you can use `FIELDS_CHANGE`. You said you need the new user id after the mutation finishes. If you're using Relay, you may need to look into `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` to specify that regardless of the computed query that Relay will build, you always want that id to be queried.

The output of your mutation is a `userType`, so you'd be able to access it with a fragment on the payload type, which would probably be `RegisterUserPayload`, that might look something like ...

```
fragment on RegisterUserPayload {
  user {
    id
  }
}
```

Now, that's assuming you're using Relay. If you'd like to try this out manually via GraphiQL, then you can use the examples of how to do mutations through there on the [GraphQL Mutation docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-mutations.html). There's a direct example of how you'd query your mutation.

Last, since you asked how to do this at a low level of issuing the HTTP request yourself, for that you can look at `express-graphql` documentation, [which explains](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#http-usage) how to query it.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks Ryan!